# How to track "complete" event of Nexage video advertisement on android?

Tags: android

There are no instructions about how i can to reward user for watching video advertisement in integration guide.

In ios we have method for that: InterstitialVideoTrackingEvent called when VAST video plays and throws tracking events. This method will help you to listen for a “complete” event and take an action based on it.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have support for tracking events in Android SDK yet. Please reach out our publisher services if you would like to have it soon.